# Rails 3 + Devise: undefined variable or method 'record' in SessionsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey,
I defined the following method in my SessionsController to sign someone out:

```
def destroy
current_user.update_attribute(:signed_in => false) if record.respond_to?(signed_in?)
signed_in = signed_in?(resource_name)
sign_out_and_redirect(resource_name)
set_flash_message :notice, :signed_out if signed_in
end
```

but I always get this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `record' for #<Devise::SessionsController:0xbcd9780>
```

Seems to me that record.respond_to? tries to access ActiveRecord but can't. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the try method.

```
current_user.try("signed_in=", false); current_user.save
```

Comment: this gives me a really weird error: <syntax error on line 47, col -1: `'>   my sessionscontroller doesn't have that many lines and I don't know what file I should look for